# How to safely exit C++ console application while working inside while(1)

Tags: c++, console, exit

I am working on Windows Embedded 7 with Visual C++ on `Toradex processor`. In my application I have to monitor the status of input pin and accordingly perform the function. To use the pins, I have to initialize a library. So the code looks like below:

```
int wmain()
{
  initLibrary();    //Initialize library

  //some code

  while(1)
  {  
    if(input1==High)
    {
     //perform some actions
    }
    if(input2==High)
    {
     //perform some actions
    }
  }

  deInitLibrary();    //de intialize the library
}
```

Above code works great. But what happens when I exit the application, the library which I have initialized at starting of the code (`initLibrary()`) keeps running in background because I have not de initialized the library. As I have to continuously monitor the status of the input pins so I have used while(1) in the code due to which the control doesn't reaches `deInitLibrary();` and doesnt de intialize the library. Thus resulting in the slow performance of the application when I run it next time.

I thought of including a `scanf()` to scan a particular character so that when it is received, I can easily break from the while(1) and de intitialize the libray to exit safely. But scanf is not a proper way because the control stops at `scanf` and doesn't move from here untill it scan a character.

Is there any way so that the scanning of char runs in background and doesn't interfere the main code and whenever a char is received, it breaks out from while loop to de initialize and exit the application. What are other ways of properly exiting the application.?

Comment: How about `std::atexit`?

Comment: @KerrekSB Hi Thanks for quick reply. where can I include it

Comment: Clearly this needs to at least be `while (keepRunning)`.  Where keepRunning is a volatile global variable that you set to *false* somewhere else,  where ever you now use exit().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) is your friend.

Wrap up your init/uninit inside an object that is guaranteed to be destructed at the end of it's scope.

**Example:**

```
class Initializer
{
public:
    Initializer()
    {
        initLibrary();
    }

    ~Initializer()
    {
        deInitLibrary();
    }
};

int wmain()
{
    Initializer init;

    while (1)
    {
        if (input1 == High)
        {
            //perform some actions
        }
        if (input2 == High)
        {
            //perform some actions
        }
    }

    // init will go out of scope and call deInitLibrary()
}
```

If you want a more generic solution than you can do something like this:

```
class Finally
{
public:
    // you can choose to use std::function instead
    typedef void(*Functor)();

    Finally(Functor functor) : functor_(functor) {}
    ~Finally() { functor_(); }

private:
    Functor functor_;
};

int wmain()
{
    initLibrary();    //Initialize library

    //some code

    Finally finally(&deInitLibrary);

    while (1)
    {
        if (input1 == High)
        {
            //perform some actions
        }
        if (input2 == High)
        {
            //perform some actions
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think local variables are not destroyed when you call `std::exit`.

Comment: @Mohamad Thanks for your answer. The class which you have made, is initializing the library at starting but how it de init it.?

Comment: It will only call `deInitLibrary` when it's destructor runs. If you are using `std::exit` to terminate your application then it's destructor will not run as @Kerrek SB mentioned. Can you show how you exit from your application?